# How do I use getElementsByClassName and how can I fix id/index mismatch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, innerhtml

I am trying to grab data from the database and format it into string to display to the user under a kendo UI dropdown list when the user makes a specific selection.

Right now I'm having problem with my JavaScript function:

```
UpdateRange: function (e) {

        var value = this.value();
        allRanges[value];
        console.log("length of range is:", allRanges[value].MinLength, "-", allRanges[value].MaxLength);
        lengthname = "length of range is:" + allRanges[value].MinLength + "-" + allRanges[value].MaxLength;
        document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = lengthname;
        var elements = lengthname;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            elements[i];
    },
```

My questions are...

I am using

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

in

```
<td></td>
```

tags which contain my kendo UI dropdownlist. I tried using getElementsByClassName and it did not work. Nothing happened. I'm not sure why... perhaps innerHTML does not work with Class Name?

How can I display the string from the database using innerHTML ?

Also, I noticed that the data in my database has ids starting with 1,2,3,4, etc... and allRanges[] is an array that starts with an index of 0. How do I align the two items so that when the user selects a value from the dropdownlist..e.g. that has a value of 4... then the array picks the value with index of 3 and not index of 4.

Comment: Stopped reading at "multiple ids". You can't do that! Also, just changing the method to getEmenentsByClassName does nothing unless you also change the markup!

Comment: Please read it all. I need something so that I can user innerhtml to display the string output from database and contain that string inside a div.

Comment: Using the same "id" multiple times is guaranteed to cause you problems. That's what you need to fix first.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like NodeList, which you can iterate through, and set the innerHTML for each one.

Comment: Yeah, use classes instead, then do document.getElementsByClassName()

Comment: I tried this: document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = lengthname; but nothing appears after a user selects an option from the dropdownlist. I'm not sure why. even though I changed all of my divs to <div class="result"></div>. For some reason, it only works with <div id="result"></div>

Comment: As @levi pointed out, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single node. Add a loop.

Comment: ohh how do I use a nodelist?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example

Comment: I still have a question with regarding mismatch of id/index though

Comment: Looping through the node list, I'm still having a bit of trouble. I updated my code to reflect the changes I've done.